# Rails: Does Application.css load all css.scss files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, sass

I read that the following line in application.css includes all the css files in the tree

```
*= require_tree .
```

My confusion is that, from what I have found out (please correct me if I am wrong), I need to add the following line into my application.haml if I want css files to load when they match with the controller rendering them:

```
    = stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller]
```

Doubt1: Do I really need to add this line? I thought it was done automatically by convention. (I am guessing the answer to this is yes, I need to include this line)

Doubt2: Since the application.css loads all the css files due to "require_tree .", would cause some kind off conflicts/messing about with each of the other css files?

Doubt3: What if I wanted to use the require_tree to load all of the skeleton files in that directory, and when a screen renders, to load in particular the controller css.

For example,

I have:

- application.css
- some_basic_styling.css
- home.css.scss
- invitation.css.scss

My application.css would include all of the css files (due to require_tree). The home.css is meant to load by the home controller, and the invitation.css is supposed to be loaded by the invitation controller. What steps do I need to ensure this?

Comment: does your layout load the application.css stylesheet ?

Comment: yes, it does. However, how does it know which styles to select if everything is loaded in application.css?

Comment: It doesn't. It's up to you to structure your css and your classes to avoid conflicts.

Comment: I get an error in heroku saying that my home.css file is not precompiled. Seems like only application.css is compile - any ideas why?

Answer (score 3):

In Rails 3.1 with asset pipeline there's a default sprocket command `require_tree .` that loads all the files in app/assets/stylesheets/ and compiles it into application.css.

The `= stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller]` command basically outputs this into your views.

`= stylesheet_link_tag :products` if viewing from the products controller.

This is *not* needed to get all the files to be compiled into application.css. All files are automatically compiled into application.css by default.

The use case of requiring a stylesheet per a controller is if you *don't* `require_tree .`. Basically, you don't want everything compiled in one stylesheet. It's the opposite of the default.